# Issue in vertical scrollbar in silverlight datagrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid

I'm using a silverlight datatgrid in my project with checkbox in the header for SelectAll option.

While scrolling the datagrid vertically, the header checkbox status is changing randomly but the content checkbox status is remains correct.

Please help me if anyone come across this issue.

```
<control:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
   <Style TargetType="control:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
         <Setter Property="PropertyNameVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
         <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#FF404040" />
         <Setter Property="SublevelIndent" Value="15" />
         <Setter Property="Template">
              <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="control:DataGridRowGroupHeader">
                  <Primitives:DataGridFrozenGrid Name="Root" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                     <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CurrentStates">
                           <VisualState x:Name="Regular"/>
                              <VisualState x:Name="Current">
                               <Storyboard>
                               <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisual" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" To="1" Duration="0" />
                                </Storyboard>
                             </VisualState>
                         </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <Primitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>
                          <ControlTemplate x:Key="ToggleButtonTemplate" TargetType="ToggleButton">
                          <Grid Background="Transparent">
                               <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                  <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                     <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                       <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                          <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Stroke).Color" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                            <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ExpandedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Fill).Color" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                      </VisualState>
                                     <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                       <Storyboard>
                                         <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="CollapsedArrow" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Stroke).Color" Duration="0" To="#FF6DBDD1"/>
```

```
                                                <Path Stretch="Uniform" Data="F1 M 0,0 L 0,1 L .6,.5 L 0,0 Z" Width="5" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="CollapsedArrow" Visibility="Collapsed" Stroke="#FF414345"/>
                                                <Path Stretch="Uniform" Data="F1 M 0,1 L 1,1 L 1,0 L 0,1 Z" Width="6" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="ExpandedArrow" Fill="#FF414345"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Primitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.Resources>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                        <RowDefinition/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Fill="#FFFDD234" Height="1"/>
                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Name="IndentSpacer" />
                                    <ToggleButton Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="ExpanderButton" Height="15" Width="15" IsTabStop="False" Template="{StaticResource ToggleButtonTemplate}" Margin="2,0,0,0"/>

                                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,1">
                                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}" Name="headerCheck" Click="headerCheck_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />
                                    </StackPanel>

                                    <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Fill="#FF4F54DA" Height="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                    <Rectangle Name="FocusVisual" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.RowSpan="3" Stroke="#FF6DB112" StrokeThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
                           VerticalAlignment="Stretch" IsHitTestVisible="false" Opacity="0" />
                                    <Primitives:DataGridRowHeader Name="RowHeader" Grid.RowSpan="3" Primitives:DataGridFrozenGrid.IsFrozen="True" />

                                </Primitives:DataGridFrozenGrid>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>
            </control:DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles>
```

Comment: Could you post the code relating to how you put the checkbox in the header of the column?

Comment: Can't able to post entire code here. I'll explain what is there in  my code. Inside the DataGrid.RowGroupHeaderStyles, created the style element with targetType as DataGridRowGroupHeader. After this created the contol template for the same targettype. Inside the controlTemplate the below code is available. <StackPanel Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,1,0,1">                                            <CheckBox Tag="{Binding}" Name="headerCheckbox" Click="headerCheckbox_Click"  HorizontalAlignment="Left"   />
    </StackPanel>

Comment: Easy way to do this is drag a checkbox from the tool box and put as select all in the datagrid.create a templatecolumn for checkbox inside datagrid, add checked and unchecked events for the checkbox when the checkbox is checked bind the value as selected.

Comment: But the problem is not in checkbox events. Whenever the headercheckbox select, the checkbox in the content group is selected as expected. but while scrolling the datagrid the header checkox status is changing i.e., it got selected even if we didn't select the header checkbox. Please find my code above.

Answer (score 0):

You have the header checkbox bound to the current item and as you scroll it changes. I would not bind this checkbox to anything unless you are using the setter to change all of the values in the ItemsSource collection. In that case make sure nothing else is changing the value of the property it is bound to.

Comment: Could you please explain with some example.

Answer (score 0):

It is due to virtualization usage by Silverlight.

I came across this problem when you scroll, data within the grid changes in terms of display. But in actuality it is the same. It is just a fact that on UI, silverlight shows it incorrectly because it uses the same controls while rendering.

The best way is to handle your logic inside LoadingRow and UnloadingRow events of the datagarid.

I have some detail posted on the following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25566163/3989725